# Search a word in TextView - android

Tags: android, search, text, textview

I have a problem: I have a text in a TextView in an android application. The users shall search a word in this text with an EditText and a button and the view should go to the word that is found and mark it. If there are more search solutions than one, it should be possible that the user can click on a 'Next' button and the next word that is found should be shown.

It's very important.
Does anybody know how to code this? THANKS for help!

Comment: Could you be a lot more specific?

Comment: Hi Nik! Of course I can be a lot more specific. I have a text in a TextView in an android application. The users shall search a word in this text with an EditText and a button and the view should go to the word that is found and mark it. If there are more search solutions than one, it should be possible that the user can click on a 'Next' button and the next word that is found should be shown.                      It's very important. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

you can get searching text from user using toolbar search view and then apply search with String.indexOf() then highlight result via SpannableString class

Comment: Yes Thanks! but do you have an idea how to click a button and then the next search result is shown and marked